# Is there another way to exact meta data from an image other than _getexif()?

Tags: python, image, metadata

I am trying to exact metadata from an img using the `_getexif()` method from the `PIL` library in Python, but I keep getting `None` returned. Can someone help me find a solution or another way to solve my problem.

```
import argparse
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


def getMetaData(imgname, out):

        metaData = {}

        imgFile = Image.open(imgname)
        print("Getting meta data...")
        info = imgFile._getexif()        
        if info:
            print("found meta data!")

            for (tag, value) in info.items():
                tagname = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                metaData[tagname] = value
                if not out:
                    print(tagname, value)
                if out:
                    print ("Outputting to file...")
                    with open(out, 'w') as f:
                        for (tagname, value) in metaData.items():
                            f.write(str(tagname)+"\t"+\
                                    str(value)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.jpg')
EXIF = im.info['exif']
```